# Open-Source cPanel alternative?

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, cpanel, control-panel

Are there any decent (i.e. stable and mature enough to use on paying clients) open-source alternatives to the cPanel web hosting control panel system?

I'm fine with paying for it, but it must be open-source so that I can add Python/Django hosting features.

Answer (score 2):

[Kloxo/HyperVM](http://lxcenter.org/) might be worth a look - open source/free and released under AGPL-3.0 license.

I can't say whether or not development is keeping pace with bugs at this point - you should know, if you use this software, that there were [some issues with security](http://www.webtalkforums.com/showthread.php/23742-LX-Labs-security-issues-%28Hyper-Vm-Lxadmin-and-Kloxo-%29-Death-of-company-owner) (which turned into some huge headaches for hosting providers) a couple years back.

**Edit:** Though the same can be said for [Webmin/Virtualmin](http://www.securiteam.com/unixfocus/5CP0R1P80G.html) - whichever platform you choose, you will definitely want to subscribe to the project's development mailing lists and keep an eye out for vulnerabilities (malicious users *love* it when they can compromise a hosting platform, so take precautions).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's open source but [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com) is freeware. I suspect you should be able to do what you need with I.