# Alternative to CPanel

Tags: vps, cpanel

I want to develop software and host it on a website. I am considering purchasing a VPS from Linode to store the source code; however it does not provide CPanel (what I used to configure my webspace on shared hosts when building websites).

Is there an alternative to CPanel or would it be worth hosting the website for the product on a shared host that provides CPanel?

Comment: Related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10152/open-source-cpanel-alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also look [ispconfig](http://www.ispconfig.org/), [alternC](http://www.alternc.org/) or [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If your moving over to using your own server then it's well worth just learning a bit about using the `shell` and just access it via `SSH`. It takes some time to get used to but is much more flexible that using GUI tools in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a VPS you could install cPanel on it. To answer the question in the last paragraph - it depends if you want more control over the server, or if cPanel gives you everything you need.